# How you bring back a network interface, after choosing NO to "Would you like USB 10/100/1000 to return next time it is connected to your Mac?"

Tags: network, usb, ethernet, driver

In Mac OS 13 Ventura (and earlier versions), there is an option to Delete network interfaces, like the one used by USB-C ethernet adapters, "USB 10/100/1000".  This produces the question,

> Would you like  to return next time it is connected to your Mac?

e.g.,

> Would you like USB 10/100/1000 LAN to return next time it is connected to your Mac?

[image: Dialog box image]

If you choose 'No', the device ***will not appear on screen when you plug the device in, the next time.***

If you choose 'No', how do your undo your choice later?

Answer (score 2):

Use `networksetup -detectnewhardware`.  From the `man` page:

```
Detects new network hardware and creates a default network service on the hardware.
```

Note that this change will not be immediately reflected in System Preferences/Settings, so quit them first.

Comment: Just did this - didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

I could not find how to undo the "no" answer.
However what did work is going to `System Settings` -> `Network` -> `...` -> `Add Service`.
Then select your device from the list and click `Create`.

Answer (score 1):

Blogger Rich Tong provided the answer in a [2017 posting:](https://tongfamily.com/2017/07/17/never-say-no-to-would-you-like-your-to-return-next-time-it-is-connect-to-your-mac/)

From the terminal, enter this command:

> ```
> sudo rm /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/NetworkInterfaces.plist
> ```